# How to add euro sign to UI.Window Text?

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-js

I'm trying to display a EUR currency amount to a `UI.Window Text`, so I try like this

```
var UI = require('ui');
var Vector2 = require('vector2');
var window = new UI.Window();

// Create TimeText
var euro = new UI.Text({
    position: new Vector2(0, 80),
    size: new Vector2(144, 30),
    text: '€ 245',
    font: 'gothic-14-bold'
});

window.add(euro);
```

While it's parsed correctly (`console.log()` of it displays `€ 245`), but the euro sign is not displayed on the Pebble. So I tried to workaround like this

```
text: "\u20AC 245",
```

but this also fails. How can I display currency symbols correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that native Pebble fonts have a narrowed set of characters. But including images (or maybe embedding fonts?) are adjuvant workarounds.